# App crashes when trying to fullscreen activity

Tags: android

Hi I'm using the code below to hide actionbar and fullscreen my activity

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

But with this code I get runtime error and app just crashes anyone know whats the problem?

Logcat:

```
       
E/AndroidRuntime(1081): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(1081): Process: com.example.directmate, PID: 1081
E/AndroidRuntime(1081): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.directmate/com.example.directmate.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:111)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at com.example.directmate.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
E/AndroidRuntime(1081):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Add your full stack trace here.

Comment: @aysaaysa Your log cat already told you the reason for the crash --> `You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.`

Comment: @aysaaysa with this logcat I think you should extend activity instead of ActionbarActivity as I said.

Comment: You are right guys appreciate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably related to your activities extend part, with this code you added to your manifest you need to extend *Activity* instead of *ActionbarActivity*

Comment: this solved my problem of course I did some other import and changed some codes

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

 setContentView(R.layout.main);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Action bar in your app and set theme for no action bar. So please sync both fro the same.